# What are the Tag edit feature limits?

Tags: discussion, support

Is there any limit to the person who edits the tags? Limits such as the number of tag edits each person can do each day.

---

It seems that if the person has many rejected tags, he is banned of tag edit for seven days. The web site gives me the following message:

> Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct. If many of your tag wiki edits are rejected (by community vote), your ability to edit tag wikis is temporarily suspended. The [exact formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92337/254250) is:

> When deciding on whether we should ban or not, we now look at your last 7 days of activity.
>
> If (rejects - (approvals / 3)) >= 5, you will be auto-banned.

You should take this as an opportunity to review *why* these edits were declined, and learn how to improve your suggested edits. [This FAQ answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/254250) explains how to see the result of your suggested edits.

Comment: Can you see were these rejected edits my recent ones or the previous edits? Because after some rejects to the edits I did last two days, I asked some questions in Meta about tag edit and tried to do better tag edits today.

Comment: @Parsa The suspension algorithm considers the last seven days of activity. You should [review your own suggested edits](http://academia.stackexchange.com/users/15723/parsa?tab=activity&sort=suggestions&page=1) to see which were rejected, and why.